# Can I set my local machine's terminal colors to use those of the machine I ssh into?

Tags: ssh, terminal, colors

I have a color scheme that I like for when I'm in a terminal, but I ssh into the machine I work on from multiple sources (locally, PuTTY, my netbook, etc.) and I want to maintain the same color scheme throughout. Is this possible?

I especially want it in PuTTY; it's difficult to change PuTTY colors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Colors in terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) are determined in two steps:

- the program running in the terminal tells the terminal to use a certain color number;
- the terminal translates each color number into a color value.

Xterm has an [escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) to change the color value associated with a color number. I don't remember whether PuTTY supports this sequence; I know [Mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) does.

```
set_color_value () {
  printf "\\e]4;$1;$2\\a"
}
set_color_value 4 '#6495ed'  # set color 4 (blue) to CornflowerBlue
```

These settings won't survive a terminal reset. You can overcome this difficulty by appending the cursor configuration changing sequence to your terminal's reset string.

- On a terminfo-based system using ncurses, save your terminal's terminfo settings to a file with `infocmp >>~/etc/terminfo.txt`. Edit the description to change the `rs1` (basic reset) sequence, e.g. replace `rs1=\Ec` by `rs1=\Ec\E]4;4;#6495ed\E\\`. With some programs and settings, you may need to change the `rs2` (full reset) as well. Then compile the terminfo description with `tic ~/etc/terminfo.txt` (this writes under the directory `$TERMINFO`, or `~/.terminfo` if unset).
- On a termcap-based system, grab the termcap settings from your termcap database (typically `/etc/termcap`). Change the `is` (basic reset) and `rs` (full reset) sequences to append your settings, e.g. `:is=\Ec\Ec\E]4;4;#6495ed\E\\:`. Set the `TERMCAP` environment variable to the edited value (beginning and ending with `:`).

Now you can put something like this in your `~/.profile`:

```
if [ "$(ps -p $PPID -o comm=)" = sshd ] &&
   [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then
  set_color_value … # set color scheme
  TERMCAP=…  # if necessary
fi
```

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding his question.... I think this has way overcomplicated things.

Comment: @xeno: I think you are misunderstanding the question. I believe Gilles got it right.

Comment: @sepp2k could be

Comment: This is a bit over my head; I am still pretty new to Linux. Am I to put the code for set_color_value() into my .bashrc? And how do I know if I'm using terminfo or termcap?

Comment: @skoh-fley: Start with putting the `set_color_value` stuff in your `.bashrc`. If you're unsure about `.bashrc` vs `.profile` vs `.bash_profile`, search on this site, [Super User](http://superuser.com/) and [Ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) where the topic has been discussed at length. You may find that the color scheme goes away when you start a full-screen application; only then should you worry about the bit about the terminal reset. If you don't know, you probably have terminfo.

Answer (score 0):

You're `ssh`-ing into just *one* box right? why not just set the `PS1` variable on that box to use the colorscheme you want? If you keep it to 16 colors you shouldn't have a problem on any modern `TERM`, most should support 256 colors, but most don't set `TERM=xterm-256color` out of the box, and some fools (*cough* my employer *cough*) sanitize `TERM` to be alpha-numeric only. Unfortunately what to put in your `PS` vars, is highly dependent on the shell you are using.

Comment: Sorry but if I understand correctly PS1 is just for the prompt, right? I want to change everything -- background, text, vim, etc.

Comment: @xenoterracide If you set that variable on a remote box, and then ssh into from a box with no colors, will you get the colored output?

Comment: If the terminal emulator supports it yes