# Overriding the shade of color displayed

Tags: terminal, kde, colors, konsole

I have to work on systems which display some colors that are hard to read. I ssh into these systems, but don't have *management permission* to change the colors they display. Is there any way I can override the shade's of colors in my terminal emulater? (I use `konsole`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each terminal emulator has its own way of setting color shades (or not). Xterm uses X resources, some of the newer emulators have dialog boxes, some have configuration files.

In Konsole, edit the color scheme in your profile (from the menu: “Settings / Edit current profile”, “Appearance” tab, select a color theme and edit it or make a new one).

There is a common [control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) to set the shade associated with a color number from the application: `OSC 4 ; c ; spec BEL` where `OSC` is `ESC ]`, `c` is the color number and `spec` is a color spec such as #RGB.

```
printf %b '\e]4;4;#6495ed\a'  # set the blue shade to CornflowerBlue
```

A change by the application is only effective until the next terminal reset. If you use this method (only recommended if your terminal lacks a configuration mechanism), to make the change effectively persistent, [append the color configuration escape sequence to your terminal's reset string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/can-i-set-my-local-machines-terminal-colors-to-use-those-of-the-machine-i-ssh-in/5937#5937) (termcap: `r1` string; terminfo: `rs1` string).

Comment: huh... I always thought color profile just changed like background/cursor/typed text didn't realize it could change other colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can modifiy `~/.Xresources` on the local machine. See [this](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xresources/solarized) for an example of themed `~/.Xresources`

Comment: The link is now broken and as a result we have no idea what you'd need to change in your `~/Xresource` to make that work...

Comment: I've updated the link

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but not under X-Windows. I have virtual boxes that I use to compile software on versions of the operating system other than the one I'm running. These have the standard "hardware console" and not a X-Terminal.

If found that the following worked for me:

```
echo -e "\\e]R\\e]PC6495ed"
```

I found that code sequence in the documentation! (duh!)

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

Note that the first part `\\e]R` is the reset sequence. So it will reset the colors to their defaults.

The second part, `\\e]PC6495ed` is what changes the blue color. Two points here:

1. The blue color is color number 12 (the C in that string)
2. The P stands for Palette

You are limited to the first 16 colors of the basic console in this case.

Comment: looks good, however doesnt do anything for me.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the "ESC ] P" sequence is now ignored. It's still in the docs, but that may just be that the docs were not updated properly.