# Dark blue color in vim or ls output in linux

Tags: terminal, colors

I have a problem with dark-blue color in `vim` or `ls` output. Because I'm using black background color, words colored in dark-blue are almost completely invisible. How can I address this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding the shade of color displayed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/overriding-the-shade-of-color-displayed)

Comment: The other thing you can do is change the colors themselves. None of the colors (even the 'dark' ones) are supposed to be unreadable on a black background. If you could specify what terminal you are using, more information could be provided if the linked question doesn't already help with this.

Comment: This looks like a problem with some displays or video card outputs. This default blue (that seems to be at least more or less the same in the linux console and in some terminal emulators) is readable on some displays, and unreadable on others.

Comment: Related: [Better colors so comments aren't dark blue in Vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88879/better-colors-so-comments-arent-dark-blue-in-vim)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can modify the color theme of vim with the `background` option. Use

```
set background=dark
```

in your current session or set it permanent in your vimrc.

The output of `ls` is configured with `/etc/DIR_COLORS`. See the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors) for more information.
The settings can be overwritten with a `~/.dir_colors` (On Ubuntu: `~/.dircolors` - see entry in `~/.bashrc`) file in your home directory.

An entry like

```
 DIR 01;36
```

will produce a more readable background with cyan.

Comment: For those new to bash: after creating your file (e.g., `~/.dircolors`) as directed here, you just have to `source ~/.bashrc` to see it working. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 36):

Rather than configure applications to avoid blue on black, I recommend configuring your terminal to make the blue more visible. Most terminal emulators have a setting for that. In xterm, there's an X resource:

```
XTerm.VT100.color4: CornflowerBlue
```

In other terminal emulators, look in the configuration file or dialog for color settings or themes.

There is a common [control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) to set the shade associated with a color number from the application: `OSC 4 ; c ; spec BEL` where `OSC` is `ESC ]`, `c` is the color number and `spec` is a color spec such as #RGB.

```
printf %b '\e]4;4;#6495ed\a'  # set the blue shade to CornflowerBlue
```

A change by the application is only effective until the next terminal reset. If you use this method (only recommended if your terminal lacks a configuration mechanism), to make the change effectively persistent, [append the color configuration escape sequence to your terminal's reset string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/can-i-set-my-local-machines-terminal-colors-to-use-those-of-the-machine-i-ssh-in/5937#5937) (termcap: `r1` string; terminfo: `rs1` string).

See also [Overriding the shade of color displayed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/overriding-the-shade-of-color-displayed), [Can I set my local machine's terminal colors to use those of the machine I ssh into?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/can-i-set-my-local-machines-terminal-colors-to-use-those-of-the-machine-i-ssh-in/5937#5937).

Comment: Solarized (http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) has nice color schemes for various terminal emulators and other programs.

Comment: if you are using GNOME Terminal, preferences -> Profile -> colours. At the bottom is a checkbox 'show bold text in bright colours'  does essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

**A faster way to set the `ls` directory color for your terminal session:**

**1.  Open your terminal run the dircolors command:**

```
machines@box790 ~ $ dircolors
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
export LS_COLORS
machines@box790 ~ $
```

It's parroting you the command for you to set the colors for ls.  The 'di' stands for directory.  34 is the bad dark blue.  36 is cyan.  So lets paste it, and change it into the terminal.

**2.  Copy that whole thing into the terminal, making a single change**

You change the `di=01;34` to `di=01;36` like this:

```
machines@box790 ~ $ LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;36:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';

machines@box790 ~ $ export LS_COLORS
```

**3.  This sets the directory colors to cyan immediately**

```
do an 'ls' and see that directories are indeed cyan.
```

**4.  Make the above step permanent**

Make it permanent by placing the above commands at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc like this:

```
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;36:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
export LS_COLORS
```

If you put this into your ~/.bashrc and (restart the terminal or `source ~/.bashrc`), the colors should still be right.

Comment: The color scheme for dircolors can be saved in a human-readable file, and applied from bashrc with eval "`dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors`". See [here](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized) colorscheme examples.

Comment: now my symlink is the same color as dir

Comment: @ealeon Ah, it does appear that directories `di` and symlinks `ln` have the same color as `01;36`.  Feel free to switch up those colors, if that particular distinction is important to you.  This colorscheme is a default one I found kicking around.

Answer (score 8):

If you inform vim that you are using a black background (or otherwise dark theme) it will lighten up all the colors so they are readable:

```
:set bg=dark
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, this work best:

```bash
LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:di=00;44"
```

[image: Screenshot of ls -lah with this color]

You can make this permanent with:

```bash
echo 'LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:di=00;44"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

This will load the `ls` colours for the current shell, replacing blue with cyan.

```bsh
eval `dircolors | sed -e 's/;34:/;36:/'`
```

It sets the environment variable `LS_COLORS`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **xfce4-terminal** I struggled with this problem for a long time until it really broke my work.

I found out, that one can change the representation for the different colors in the "Palette" in the "xfce4-terminal"-settings. So that dark-blue would be represented as light-blue or anything else that fits your background-color. See screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run `dircolors`, you will see something like `di=01;34`. Here, `01` means bold. So you just need to change it to `00`, which means default color. You could add

```
eval `dircolors | tr 01 00`
```

in your `.bashrc.`

I use MobaXterm and it works for me.