# Better colors so comments aren't dark blue in Vim?

Tags: vim, colors, editors, color-management

Mostly I edit Ruby files, although shell script file comments are also `#`

Currently my comments show as dark blue on black which is really hard to read.

See screenshot.

How can I change their color?

I'm willing to consider different schemas for all colors though I do like the black background as a base.

[image: A screenshot of a terminal window with Vim running in it. The comments are dark blue on black background making them hardly visible.]

Comment: I like a contrasting background for comments -- it sets them off from the code, eg. `hi Comment ctermbg=gray ctermfg=darkblue`.  You can set your color scheme and then change it bit by bit; put the bits in a seperate file and `source` it from your vimrc at the end.

Comment: *TL;DR* Just edit ~/.vimrc and add the line 
    colorscheme desert

Comment: All these years later, how is this still the default?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

There are many color schemes which are usually distributed together with vim. You can select them with the `:color` command.

You can see the available color schemes in vim's `colors` folder, for example in my case:

```
$ ls /usr/share/vim/vimNN/colors/ # where vimNN is vim version, e.g. vim74
blue.vim  darkblue.vim  default.vim  delek.vim  desert.vim  elflord.vim 
evening.vim  koehler.vim  morning.vim  murphy.vim  pablo.vim  peachpuff.vim
README.txt  ron.vim  shine.vim  slate.vim  torte.vim  zellner.vim
```

I usually use `desert`. So I open `vim`, then enter `:color desert` and enter. To have the color scheme by default every time you open `vim`, add `:color desert` into your `~/.vimrc`.

(Michael, OP)  This was good.  The terminal looks like:

[image: Example of VIM on a Ruby file showing syntax highlighting in various colors]

Comment: You can also cycle through available colors with TAB after typing `:color`.

Comment: In my case it was in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/`.

Comment: Good choices that work the same on powershell/wsl/ubuntu: `:colorscheme industry` (medium contrast) `:colorscheme elflord` (hard contrast) and `:colorscheme evening` (soft contrast)

Comment: Thanks @Daddy32. It showed all the schemes. For some reason I was hoping you'd get a preview of how it'd look with the schemes when you cycle through, but at least you get to see all available names.

Answer (score 201):

As you are using a dark background in your terminal, you simply need to set

```
:set background=dark
```

instead of the default

```
:set background=light
```

The colors are then automatically correctly set.

If you want to have this permanently, add the line

```
set background=dark
```

to your `$HOME/.vimrc` file.

Comment: While the accepted answer has useful information, this answer is far more concise about the root cause of the problem for folks like myself who prefer a dark themed terminal window.

Comment: Unfortunately this still uses that almost unreadable dark blue in places.

Comment: @rooby Often, you can change the default colors in your terminal emulator, see also the other answers.

Comment: It seems rather strange that debian (at least) defaults to a dark background for its terminal window but the same distribution's vim defaults to a light background assumption about the terminal.

Comment: I think you can also just use `bg` instead of `background`

Answer (score 40):

You can do it manually with this command:

```
:hi Comment guifg=#ABCDEF
```

Where `ABCDEF` is an appropriate [color hex code](http://www.color-hex.com/).

To make it permanent, you will need to add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` file (using green as an example):

```
syntax on
:highlight Comment ctermfg=green
```

Comment: It's also possible to see your current highlight settings with `:hi` or `:highlight` (i.e. without any other arguments).

Comment: You can also change other types such as strings in supporting document types, example `:highlight String ctermfg=green`

Comment: Editing the answer to remove the "googling" bits makes the answer appear a bit inconsistent: first, we have the use of `guifg` in the commandline and then, to "make it permanent" we have `ctermfg`.

Comment: Colour hex codes are easy enough to look up, but what about a link to the list of magic words (ie. "Comment" etc.)?

Comment: @EdRandall you will need to use some unfortunate soul who chooses to use vim. I'm an emacs user so I can't help.

Comment: The correct element to modify depends on the type of file you are editing.  For a bash script, the `highlight` command shows it is `Special` that is dark blue on black (in my current color scheme named `pablo`).  Thus I was able to fix my current editing session with the vim command `:highlight Special term=bold ctermfg=81 guifg=#00ffff`.   The right element name (kinda like a CSS class name) will be different for C++ source code, etc.  0x00FFFF is Cyan.

Answer (score 16):

One option I found was in terminal preferences (top menu, not the window).

This has profile preferences and then a color tab, e.g.

[image]

Changing the Palette entry 5 from Dark blue to Light Lilac helped.  I finally chose xterm as the color scheme and lightened up the comment color e.g.[image]

Comment: My only question now is if whether I can now save those preferences in a file so that they are there for a new machine setup.

Comment: I use xterm, and set the blue color to something palatable to my eyes in .Xresources: "XTerm*color4: light sky blue".

Answer (score 11):

I had precisely this problem a little while ago, the solution is to place the following line in your vimrc file:

```
set t_Co=256
```

And then you might have to put the following at the end of your your ~/.profile:

```
#set vim terminal to 256 colors.
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
    export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

and then you can set:

```
hi Comment      ctermfg=lightblue
```

in your vimrc file and then you will have light blue comments.
vimrc 256: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim

I also noticed the screen became somewhat prettier by setting it to 256.

Answer (score 7):

If on a dark background in Debian, then uncommenting `set background=dark` in `/etc/vim/vimrc` helps, too.

Or, if you don't want to interfere with the package's config file, rather in (a new)
`/etc/vim/vimrc.local`

Answer (score 4):

Here is nice git repo with 700+ colorschemes for vim

https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes

clone it to `~/.vim/`

```
git clone https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes ~/.vim/
```

Preview schemes in vim with

```
:colorscheme mrkn256
```

(replace `mrkn256` with one of these names `ls ~/.vim/colors` (without the `.vim` extension ))

To set it permanently edit `~/.vimrc` add/change

```
colorscheme mrkn256
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate your own gvim colors and paste them into your vimrc.
Using chrome http://www.hmi-tech.in/activities/gvim-color-scheme-interactive-generator.html 
[image: Interactive Color picker to generate vim hilight colors]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too far off topic but here goes

For Windows 10 WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

this worked for me (in `.vimrc`)

```
syntax on

colorscheme desert "(or whatever color scheme)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "colorscheme elflord" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Then re-run.
I like it, light comments.

Answer (score -1):

Create a file on user's home

```
root@ip-10-100-4-227:~# vi .vimrc
```

Enter below syntax in file

```
syntax on
colorscheme desert
```

Source File

```
root@ip-10-100-4-227:~# source .vimrc
```

Answer (score -2):

```
:colo desert
```

I use this command to highlight the comments for example ;)