# VI (which vi => /usr/bin/vim) showing too many colors in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, vim, colors, vi

Hello I am writing code using vi (which is /usr/bin/vim in GNU/Linux).  It puts too many colors (especially when I put a comment with "#").

Please let me know following:

1) Is there a way to not show colors in VI?

2) Is there a better VI which doesn't put strain on eyes?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88879/135943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off syntax highlighting.

```
:syntax off
```

Alternatively, adjust the color scheme.  (https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2995/4676)

Type `:colorscheme` (with a space afterwards) and then press Ctrl-D to list the possible completions.  On my copy of Vim this shows the following colorschemes are available:

```
:colorscheme
blue       default    desert     evening    morning    pablo      ron        slate      zellner
darkblue   delek      elflord    koehler    murphy     peachpuff  shine      torte
:colorscheme
```

Then just type the name of the colorscheme (e.g. `:colorscheme blue`), using tab completion if you like, and voila!

---

If you don't like the existing colorschemes, you can install them from a third party, or even [create your own](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2782/4676).